# Can I customize my default Beaker notebook?

Tags: beaker-notebook

The Beaker homepage has a button that says default notebook that creates a notebook with some sample cells.  Can I customize this notebook with my own content?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, create a notebook you like and save it to **~/.beaker/v1/config/default-notebook.bkr**. This will be loaded when you click the 'New Default Notebook' button, or use the Control-Shift-N keyboard equivalent.

The default notebook that comes with Beaker has Python and R cells as well as some tips for beginners. It would be normal for advanced users to customize the included languages (for example, adding a standard JAR to their Groovy classpath), remove the tips, and add a signature cell with their contact information.